# PHP check database table, if value exists, run loop to generate unique value

Tags: php, mysql

I have function which checks if value exists, in this case it is API key. What I am trying to achieve is, before creating new api key for each account registration, I want to loop my function to generate new key if existing already in database. Key is simple string generated using:

```
$apiKey = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
```

My function:

```
function apiCheckKey($apiKey) {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `api` WHERE `key` = '".$apiKey."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My check:

```
if(!apiCheckKey($apiKey)) {
     // loop
}
```

How can I run loop efficiently to generate new key and eliminate duplicates? Please keep in mind, database will contain 100 000+ records...

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: thank your suggestion, I will for sure, but how to find solution in my existing case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things to keep in mind when doing this:

1. Ensure you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on this column so it's impossible to add duplicate values. You can't rely on a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE key=?` test before inserting as that's vulnerable to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).
2. Generate an API key that's sufficiently random that collisions are unlikely. A >=20 character random string using all letters, both upper and lower case, plus numbers will have 704,423,425,546,998,022,968,330,264,616,370,176 possible forms so a collision is astronomically unlikely. If you have shorter keys collisions become a lot more probable due to effects like [the pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) and the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).
3. In the unlikely event a collision does occur, make your code generate a new key and retry the insert. A `UNIQUE` constraint violation is a very specific MySQL error code you can handle. Check your `error` value if/when the `INSERT` fails and dispatch accordingly.

Test your code by generating a few million keys to be sure it's operating properly.

Comment: Thank you for opinion. What do you think if I will generate string using bin2hex(random_bytes(16))? It returns 32 character string like 0C86B1508F236945534705C0661F59A9. Maybe it is not a bad idea for API key?

Comment: Anything that's "cryptographically secure" like `random_bytes` is should do, but keep in mind that there are only 16 hex values instead of 62 letters, so that's a significantly smaller key space and collisions are more likely. You can use `base64_encode` instead to generate 64-possible values, then substitute `/` and `+` with arbitrary letters to avoid having unusual junk in your key.

Comment: Thank you! You helped a lot.